# using c++ can you set the output directory to a web page input box?

Tags: html, visual-c++, io

My brother was asking me if I could make him a program that would ask the user for info (name, address, etc) and then output it on a webpage text box that he uses. The reason for this is he has to write the same info over and over for his job so if he could enter it once and have a program fill the correct fields in that would save him hours every day. I've taken a couple semesters of c++ and I was thinking I could write a GUI program just fine that would get the info needed, my problem is I don't know if it is possible to set the output directory to a html text box. I've never messed around with html coding at all. It would be the same web page every time with the same boxes to fill. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No. An input element on a web page is not a file.

An appropriate way to solve this problem would be with a Javascript browser add-on.